# How to access the map coordinates show in QGIS status bar?

Tags: qgis, python, coordinates

Is there a way to access the map coordinates show in qgis status bar? I found only this,

```
iface.mainWindow().statusBar().currentMessage()
```

But I know it's not the way.

Or is there any way to capture the coordinates when cursor moves on map?

Answer (score 2):

You can get what you see down there using these methods:

```
iface.mapCanvas().extent().center()
iface.mapCanvas().extent().toString()
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I want to automatically change a QTextBrowser with that value when cursor moves on map. Is there any way I can do it? any signal to emit when cursor moves?

Comment: http://qgis.org/api/classQgsMapCanvas.html#abf90fbd211ea419ded7c934fd289f0ab

Comment: Can you please help me to write that line.I'm very new to this field. I wrote one for mouse click event and it works. 'QObject.connect(self.clickTool, SIGNAL("canvasClicked(const QgsPoint &, Qt::MouseButton)"), self.handleMouseDown)' Can you please help me to write same like this for cursor movements.

Comment: @Dil please accept this answer if it solves the problem stated in your question. If you have a new question afterwards, please open a new thread.

Comment: OK underdark. I will ask a separate question. Thank You